# converting yolo format .txt files into csv table

Tags: python, object-detection

txt files generated from labelimg ,the txt files need to convert into one csv table with x_center, y_center , height ,and weight some txt files contains more than one line of flies
then the same image_id should have two set of rows each i was able to read only one line of txt file ,but unable to read more than one values in .txt file

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


os.chdir(r'D:\karami\Labeled\train1\labels')
myFiles = glob.glob('*.txt')

width=1024
height=1024
image_id=0
final_df=[]
for item in myFiles:
    row=[]
    bbox_temp=[]
    with open(item, 'rt') as fd:
        first_line = fd.readline()
        splited = first_line.split();
        
        row.append(image_id)
        row.append(width)
        row.append(height)
        try:
            bbox_temp.append(float(splited[1])*width)
            bbox_temp.append(float(splited[2])*height)
            bbox_temp.append(float(splited[3])*width)
            bbox_temp.append(float(splited[4])*height)
            row.append(bbox_temp)
            final_df.append(row)
        except:
            print("file is not in YOLO format!")
df = pd.DataFrame(final_df,columns=['image_id', 'width', 'height','bbox'])
df.to_csv("saved.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: What is "yolo format"?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


os.chdir(r'D:\karami\Labeled\train1\labels')
myFiles = glob.glob('*.txt')

width=1024
height=1024
image_id=0
final_df=[]
for item in myFiles:
    row=[]
    bbox_temp=[]
    image_id+=1
    with open(item, 'rt') as fd:
        for line in fd.readlines():
           splited = line.split():
           row.append(image_id)
           row.append(width)
           row.append(height)
           try:
               bbox_temp.append(float(splited[1])*width)
               bbox_temp.append(float(splited[2])*height)
               bbox_temp.append(float(splited[3])*width)
               bbox_temp.append(float(splited[4])*height)
               row.append(bbox_temp)
               final_df.append(row)
           except:
               print("file is not in YOLO format!")
df = pd.DataFrame(final_df,columns=['image_id', 'width', 'height','bbox'])
df.to_csv("saved.csv",index=False)
```

if you are trying to convert between formal data annotation type like COCO, PascalVOC, YOLO use python library such as [imgann](https://pypi.org/project/imgann/), to reduce code errors and time.

Answer (score 0):

''' This file is used to convert annotations from .txt file to tenforflow csv formate
'''

```
import os
import os.path
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
def write_to_csv(ann_path ,img_path ,dict):
    annos = []    #Kindly adjust the indentations
    # Read txts  
    for files in os.walk(ann_path): #Kindly adjust the indentations
      for file in files[2]:
        print (file + "-->start!")
        # Read image and get its size attributes
        img_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.jpg'
        fileimgpath = os.path.join(img_path ,img_name)
        im = Image.open(fileimgpath)
        w = int(im.size[0])
        h = int(im.size[1])

        # Read txt file 
        filelabel = open(os.path.join(ann_path , file), "r")
        lines = filelabel.read().split('\n')
        obj = lines[:len(lines)-1]  
        # name = dict[obj[0]]
        for i in range(0, int(len(obj))):
             objbud=obj[i].split(' ')                
             name = dict[objbud[0]]
             # print(name)
             x1 = float(objbud[1])
             y1 = float(objbud[2])
             w1 = float(objbud[3])
             h1 = float(objbud[4])
             xmin = int((x1*w) - (w1*w)/2.0)
             ymin = int((y1*h) - (h1*h)/2.0)
             xmax = int((x1*w) + (w1*w)/2.0)
             ymax = int((y1*h) + (h1*h)/2.0)
             annos.append([img_name ,w ,h ,name ,xmin ,ymin ,xmax ,ymax])
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax' ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(annos, columns=column_name)        
    print(annos[:10])
    return df
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    # Argument Parser
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True, help="txt path")
    ap.add_argument("-img", "--image", required=True, help="images path")
    ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True, help="output csv path ")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args()) 

   # Define class number according to the  classes in the .txt file
    dict = {'0' : 'autorickshaw',
        '1': "bus",
        '2': "car",
        '3': "motorcycle",
        '4': "truck",
        '5': "vehicle fallback",
        }      
    # Assign paths        
    ann_path = args["input"]
    img_path = args["image"]
    csv_path = args["output"]  

    data=write_to_csv(ann_path ,img_path  ,dict)      
    # print()
    data.to_csv(csv_path, index=None)
    print('Successfully converted xml to csv. And your output file is {}'.format(args["output"])) 

  # Command to run the code : 
  #python3 txt_to_csv.py -i path_of_Text_files_labels_directory -img data\images -o data\data.csv
  #Output format will be 
  #filename ,height ,width ,class ,xmin ,ymin ,xmax ,ymax
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).